# Are Netezza and Hive for Hadoop ACID compliant?

Tags: hadoop, hql, netezza, acid

I have read that Netezza is ACID compliant. While I have also read that Netezza doesn't enforce foreign keys which means C of ACID is violated. Also Netezza (until version 7.1.0.0 ) didn't support commit/rollback in stored procedure like in Oracle. Which means A of ACID is violated. What is the correct answer? Is Netezza ACID compliant? If so how?

Hive does not have commit/rollback for multiple statements as part of one transaction like in Oracle but does guarantee that each single transaction is performed in entirety or not which makes it Atomic. It does not enforce pk, fk but does guarantee the consistency of database. So, I believe it's ACID compliant but it is said that it's not. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netezza is ACID compliant.  It's true that primary/foreign key definitions are informational only, and are not enforced, however that is not a violation of Consistency.  Because primary or foreign keys are informational only in Netezza, it's not an invalid state to have data that doesn't conform to the primary key definition.

Similarly, while earlier versions of Netezza didn't offer explicit transaction control within stored procedures, every stored procedure was implicitly its own transaction when outside of a BEGIN/COMMIT, and in that case a transaction is still either fully committed on completion or fully rolled back on an abort, thereby maintaining Atomicity.

If you call a stored procedure within a BEGIN/COMMIT block then the stored procedure returns an active transaction block, and must be explicitly committed rolled back.

The newer behavior where COMMITs are allowed in a store procedure does give rise to different behavior, though.

Comment: Exactly. FK in Netezza is only informational. Isn't 'C'onsistency of ACID meant to impose datatype, pk, fk constraints?

As for Atomicity, let's say as a part of single transaction I want to perform two updates on two tables in a plsql block. Since it is part of the same transaction I of course want to commit only at the end of both. What if the system goes down after the first update statement? How would that guarantee 'A'tomicity?

Comment: The Consistency here is only relevant to fk and pk constraints if they are enforced. If they are not enforced, then they are not relevant to whether the database is in a valid state or not.  If Netezza *did* enforce them, then they would be relevant to Consistency. With regard to Atomicity, you are (or were, pre-7.x) limited to the scope of transactions within a stored procedure, however the transactions that do occur within a stored procedure are Atomic, you just can't (or couldn't, pre-7.x) make multiple statements be part of a single transaction with a stored procedure.

Comment: I see what you are saying. My understanding of ACID was something different [here](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/07/acid-properties-by-example-and-counterexample-part-zero/). This whole thing started when I started looking if Hive for Hadoop is ACID compliant or not. By your definition I can say that even HQL is ACID compliant which actually is not. Never mind if you have not worked in Hadooop. I have changed the title to get inputs for HQL.

Comment: Swart's blog on the topic is good. But keep an eye on the technical definition.  He defines "Consistency - A transaction reaching its normal end, thereby committing its results, preserves the consistency of the DB. In other words, each successful transaction by definition commits only legal results."  Choose to enforce those constraints & you have to stick by that. A DB that doesn't enforce constraints can violate them & be OK. An ACID DB guarantees that the DB is valid within its rules, not the app's.  Because constraints are simply informational, the DB data is still valid & consistent.